# Six featured tags shown, but I have seven

Tags: bug, status-norepro, new-nav

It is great that I can see all activity for all my favourite (low-volume) tags. This saves me lots of clicks.

However, I have seven favourite tags, and only six (the first six, from left-to-right of my favourites) which are used to filter questions. Is the seventh off-by-one or is there a limit?

Seems I can have seven custom tags, but only six favourites go in the filter. I can't find an explanation of what custom tags are, they look to be my favourites (less one) plus any I want to add for that particular search.

No, turns out the custom tags are the most recent tag selection to which tags can be added.

I close the browser tab, start a new one, and by default I get by first tag only filtering the list. Custom tags at this point contains that single tag. I select favourite tags, and then custom tags shows six of my seven favourites and allows me to add the seventh.

Still good stuff.

Comment: Does one of them have a wildcard?

Comment: @Joe No, tthey are just plain tags.

Comment: I just hit this a few minutes ago and was confused why my last tag was not in the list. Sounds like it might be an off-by-one error.

Comment: @KevinBrown The only ohter thing I can think is that I originally created six tags and later added the seventh. Possibly. Off-by-one in some manner sounds more likely.

Comment: Can you detail which six tags filter and which is the one that doesn't?

Comment: Yes, my favorites are: cobol mainframe dfsort syncsort jcl easytrieve comp-3 . The comp-3 does not get included. When I first discovered favorite tags, I put in the first six. Maybe. Definitely comp-3 was the last one I added to favorites. I've not played around with anything in case it messes up an example. @KevinBrown perhaps can also comment.

Comment: @BillWoodger there is a six tag limit with favorites but only in a specific case: if you don't have *any* specified favorite, we pick the 6 tags you are most active in.

Comment: Mmmm... are you saying my favorite tags aren't favorite enough? My six most active tags are: cobol mainframe jcl syncsort opencobol and ibm. I have the seven Favorite Tags previously mentioned, no advanced tag subscriptions and no ignored tags. When I select the favourite tags filter it shows me (6), the first six detailed above.

Comment: @BillWoodger the favorite tags get sorted alphabetically when you use the favorite filter. I tried setting my favorites like yours and get "cobol comp-3 dfsort easytrieve jcl mainframe syncsort". Can you confirm you are getting "cobol dfsort easytrieve jcl mainframe syncsort"?

Comment: Yes, I am getting them sorted in that order with comp-3 missing: cobol dfsort easytrieve jcl mainframe syncsort as you suggest.

Comment: The only thing I can emphasise if you get seven correct when you add them is that comp-3 was definitely the last one added, and added some time after the others.

Comment: After adding a new tag ([tag:jquery-select2-3]), this issue fixed itself on Stack Overflow. Before that, [tag:jquery-select2-4] was not being included, and it was the last one I had added.

Comment: @Sklivvz I've encountered a somewhat similar bug (but I'm not sure it's the same, should I report it separately?). I visited http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=needanswer&layout=expanded&tagFilter=favorite then later removed a tag ([tag:python]) from my favorite tag list. Hours later, this tag was still included in the need-answer/favorite list. I just tried to add a tag ([tag:rust]), and now the need-answer/favorite list properly includes the tag I added and doesn't include the tag I removed. There does seem to be an intermittent refresh problem when favorite tags are modified.

Comment: @Gilles given that we are dealing with "OR" tags, isn't it possible that you were seeing "python" questions because another tag matched as well?

Comment: @Sklivvz No, I did check, and I even saw a question tagged only [tag:python]. I'm experimenting a bit right now and I wonder if it has to do with the method I used to add a tag. I unfavorited [tag:python] by clicking on the star in the tag popup. I favorited [tag:rust] by going into my preferences. Just now I unfavorited [tag:build] from the “Favorite Tags” box in the sidebar and it took effect instantly. I unfavorited [tag:mercurial] by clicking on the star in the tag popup and it hasn't taken effect in a couple of minutes. So maybe the route used to (un)favorite is the issue?

Comment: @Sklivvz Ok, I can reproduce this. Adding or removing a favorite tag via the star in the popup on hover doesn't update the list used by the need-answer/favorite view. Editing favorites via the profile preferences or the sidebar updates the need-answer/favorite list on refresh. Bill, did you add [tag:comp-3] via the popup on hover by any chance?

Comment: Filtering by favorites simply loads the favorites when the page is generated. Changing them in the sidebar doesn't automatically refresh the page. You can however change them in the list under the filters (which then makes the filter go from "Favorites (n)" to "Custom"

Comment: @Gilles Thanks, but no. Going through your posts I can see what you mean, but that's the first time I've seen that. I found a question by accident. I probably/possibly added the tag to the question. I possibly even created the tag comp-3 myself. All I can reliably remember about making it a favourite is that it was definitely after the others.

Comment: @BillWoodger I don't understand your comment. In my test, I found that what mattered was which interface I used to (un)favorite a tag. One method (clicking on the cross/star in the popup when hovering over a tag name) doesn't refresh the need-answer/favorite filter, which is consistent with what you observed.

Comment: @Sklivvz Was your last comment directed at me or at Bill? It doesn't seem to make sense either way. I've [made a new bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257324/the-need-answer-favorite-view-is-not-updated-when-unfavoriting-a-tag-via-the-p), since I'm not sure whether Bill and I have encountered the same bug.

Comment: @Gilles I know I didn't favourite the comp-3 tag the way you have explained, because I didn't know it was possible to do it that way. I don't remember exactly how I did do it, however.

Comment: @Sklivvz Just an update, I eventually went with removing the tag from my favourites and re-adding it. Works fine. Thanks for looking, and thanks for work on the feature, which I find a real pleasure to use.